# ResizeCanvas behaviour unknown prop in Graphin when using React functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple functional component with G6 React wrapper Graphin.

```
const TheGraph = () => {
 return (
    <Graphin
      data={data}
      fitView={true}
      layout={{
        type: 'gForce',
        linkDistance: 10,
        preventOverlap: true,
        workerEnabled: true,
        gpuEnabled: true,
        maxIteration: 300,
      }}
    >
      <DragNode/>
      <ResizeCanvas graphDOM={ ??? what to put here ??? }/>
      <ActivateRelations trigger="click"/>
    </Graphin>
  )
}
```

The issue is with this behaviour, in the [documentation](https://graphin.antv.vision/en-US/graphin/behaviors/canvas/) it says I have to pass "this.graphDOM", and it's mandatory. But `this`means nothing in a functional component. Plus, I have no idea what graphDOM is or where to get it from.